# Can you change the color of start screen tiles?

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-interface, display-settings

I recently upgraded to Windows 8.1. It is working fine for me except that now the app tiles in the start screen use the color of the icon for the tile background. This makes it very difficult to find apps. Any icon that is flat disappears into the background. For these apps I must rely on the labels to find out what they are.

Is there a way to change the background color of app tiles?
This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by Google Search and am sorry to say that I cannot test it. I am still using Windows 8.

The answer to your question:
[How to customize Start screen tiles for desktop apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx)

Comment: This is great to know, I am going to fix tons of annoyances with the start screen (even though I rarely use my W8.1 box or the Start Screen).

Comment: Their documentation lists two XML attributes as optional near the top, but I think there's a typo in the second one; I doubt the 70x70 png should be under an attribute named 150x150.  I sent them a feedback email about the page content.

Comment: I followed the steps to create the xml file, but I don't understand what to do for step 7. They don't give much explanation for this step. Could someone please explain?

Comment: We really expect more to an answer then a link to another website. Besides if you cannot fomfirm the answer works its not really helpfu ( which appears to be the case ). Besides this particular article is for the programmer of the program in question not the user.